# Ubuntu One file sync error: SSL Handshake

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, ssl

Ubuntu One repeatedly tries to sync my files but keeps disconnecting before anything is uploaded. Here are some of the messages from syncdaemon.log:

```
2012-01-08 12:12:34,068 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection started to host fs-2.ubuntuone.com, port 443.
2012-01-08 12:12:34,256 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection made.
2012-01-08 12:12:34,257 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection made.
2012-01-08 12:13:08,832 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection lost, reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]].
2012-01-08 12:13:08,833 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'protocol_version' failed with the error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
2012-01-08 12:13:08,844 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Connection lost: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
2012-01-08 12:13:38,550 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Main - NOTE - ---- MARK (state: <State: 'WAITING'  (queues WORKING  connection 'With User With Network')>; queue: 1378; hash: 0) ----
2012-01-08 12:15:08,870 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection started to host fs-2.ubuntuone.com, port 443.
2012-01-08 12:15:09,033 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection made.
2012-01-08 12:15:09,034 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection made.
2012-01-08 12:15:33,676 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection lost, reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]].
2012-01-08 12:15:33,677 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'protocol_version' failed with the error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
2012-01-08 12:15:33,692 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Connection lost: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]
2012-01-08 12:15:38,551 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Main - NOTE - ---- MARK (state: <State: 'WAITING'  (queues WORKING  connection 'With User With Network')>; queue: 1378; hash: 0) ----
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: This is also occurring with 11.04. It appears there's an issue with Canonical's servers that's preventing anyone from getting online with U1.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug report about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/887915), which is marked as invalid. Apparently it's a momentary issue (either with your network connection or with Canonical servers).